# Xgboost tuning fails

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am trying to classify patients into those who have diabetes and those who do not, with xgboost and scikit-learn library.
The dataset is from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/cjboat/diabetes2).

The Y column is "Outcome", and contains 0 or 1.

when tuning the hyperparameters, I get an error in the last line of code:

```
File "D:\code\python\ml\venv\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 1803, in eval_set
  _check_call(
File "D:\code\python\ml\venv\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 203, in _check_call
  raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
xgboost.core.XGBoostError: [19:20:51] C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/xgboost-win64_release_1.6.0/src/metric/multiclass_metric.cu:35: Check failed: label_error >= 0 && label_error < static_cast<int32_t>(n_class): MultiClassEvaluation: label must be in [0, num_class), num_class=1 but found 1 in label
```

It is worth noting that a regular run of xgboost without tuning works well.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from skopt import BayesSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

diabetes2_path = r"D:\code\python\ml\datasets\classification\diabetes(2).csv"

df = pd.read_csv(diabetes2_path)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, df["Outcome"], test_size=0.25)

params = {'max_depth': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 20],
          'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2],
          'subsample': np.arange(0.5, 1.0, 0.1),
          'colsample_bytree': np.arange(0.4, 1.0, 0.1),
          'colsample_bylevel': np.arange(0.4, 1.0, 0.1),
          'min_child_weight': (0, 30),
          'gamma': (0, 20),
          'num_class': np.arange(2),
          'n_estimators': (50, 1000)}

xgbr = xgb.XGBClassifier(enable_categorical=True, tree_method='hist')
# xgbr.fit(X_train, y_train)
# result = xgbr.predict(X_test) # works great!

kfold = KFold(n_splits=3)
search = BayesSearchCV(estimator=xgbr,
                       search_spaces=params,
                       scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
                       n_iter=25,
                       verbose=0)

eval_set = [(X_test, y_test)]
result = search.fit(X_train, y_train, early_stopping_rounds=10, eval_metric="mlogloss",
                    eval_set=eval_set)  # ERROR!!
```

Comment: Always provide the full error traceback.

Comment: The error looks like some fold doesn't have both of the labels.  The train-test split automatically shuffles, so that's not likely the culprit, unless maybe the dataset is very small; and the search defaults to a stratified 3-fold, so that doesn't seem it either.  It's possible that subsampling does it?  Try without that hyperparameter?

Comment: The full error traceback is very long, so I added now only the last lines.

Comment: It works great without hyperparameter. the dataset contains 769 rows.

Comment: How many instances of class 1?

Comment: 500 with 0 value. 268 with 1 value.